# How to select an UIView on screen based on X/Y coordinate

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I have several UIViews on screen, none of them overlapping, and I would like to select an UIView based on X/Y coordinates on screen (screen as the entire view dimension, so 320x568 for iPhone 5) to make a transformation to the selected UIView  For example, in the image below, I would like to select the **blue** rectangle based on entering `(40,40)`, and then perform a transformation such as changing its color to red.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIView implements a method called hitTest:withEvent: ([see docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a)) that will answer the deepest view in your view hierarchy that contains a given point.

Use it like this:

```
// in the view controller subclass
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(40.0, 40.0);
UIView *subviewContainingPoint = [self.view hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

UIViews have a `tag` property that is probably a much easier way to accomplish what you are looking for.

You can set the tag in interface builder, or you can set it programatically.

```
UIView* newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,z,a)];
[newView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
newView.tag = 1;
[self addSubview:newView];
```

later you can access that view by calling the `viewWithTag` method on a view further up the hierarchy, and then do something to it

```
[[self viewWithTag:1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

While it's not impossible to locate your views by querying their frames and doing some math on the resulting coordinates, chances are very good that tags will serve you better.